# No internet once connected to OpenVPN server

Tags: internet, vpn, openvpn, webserver

I'm new here so please do not hesitate if you need additional informations :)

I have an old PC on which one I have installed Ubuntu with a web server (PHP, MySQL...) so that I can access all of its services (Web (port 80), SSH and FTP) from my local network via local IP 192.168.1.X (static).

Now, I want to be able to connect to the local network and do the same things but from everywhere in the world. Moreover, I want the connection to be secure: what I mean is that I don't want anybody to access my web pages.

The best solution I found is via VPN: I installed OpenVPN server and now I can access SSH, FTP and web from everywhere. The last problem is that, when I am connected to the VPN, I haven't any internet connection. I cannot understand why the OpenVPN server does not handle the requests.

To setup the OpenVPN server, I used [this](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install), using my PC's local IP for the first step and using my router's IP when asked for NATed connection details.

After many attemps, I am asking you some help.
If you need any log or info, just ask :)

Thanks !

Comment: I did not specify it in my post, but I did **a lot** of research on the web

Comment: Tecnically if you're connected to the vpn you have internet connection. I've recently connected to a network where i was able to see the other machines but no "internet connection". The problem was the dns server, there wasn't any configured as default. Ping google dns server `ping 8.8.8.8`, if you can ping it, the problem is solvable with `echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee --append /etc/resolv.conf && echo 'nameserver 8.8.4.4' | sudo tee --append /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, thanks to bistoco's answer, I changed the DNS on both the ubuntu server and the client (Windows) to Google's one (8.8.8.8) because I was able to ping it successfully. On ubuntu, [I used the GUI](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/dns#par_interface_graphique); on Windows, I changed the DNS for my wifi card and for the OpenVPN TAP Adapter.

I hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my reputation wont allow for comments. So an answer. Seems like your you didnt update your configuration. This answer works but the internet connectivity is very slow. This [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/849234/openvpn-client-connects-to-server-but-name-resolution-does-not-work) is better. To sum up things mentioned there, you need to update your ubuntu DNS configuration at the client side. Add the following lines in the openvpn key

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I have missed to setup this.

**Packet Forwarding**

This is a sysctl setting which tells the server’s kernel to forward traffic from client devices out to the Internet. Otherwise, the traffic will stop at the server. Enable packet forwarding during runtime by entering this command:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

We need to make this permanent so the server still forwards traffic after rebooting.

```
vim /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Near the top of the sysctl file... Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Save your changes and exit.

Ref.: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04